# Need .NET controls serialization

Tags: json, serialization, c#-4.0, controls, hook

I need to serialize every control of a .NET managed process (whether it's main form, child controls like buttons, calender, text boxes, list boxes, combos, etc). Every simple class object is easily serializable/deserializable using binary formaters, but these controls (which I got their info through `reflection(Type.GetFields(), Type.GetProperties())`) are not serializing through this serialization method which I described.

It throws a `"type System.Forms.Form.WinForm to be serialize"` exception. After serialization I need to pass the control's information as it is, to another remote process.

How can I get the .NET control's information to be serializable? (Json?)

Comment: Json is less strongly types than XML or the .NET Binary serializer. It would be harder to do this via JSON than other methods.

Comment: Why do you need to serialize the controls? Where will you store the serialized data?

Comment: I need to send these controls information to other process which will use that information and will re-draw and create custom controls from this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-421612.html has an answer for you